# Using array_map vs array_column and array_combine in php

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

Let's say I have an associative array like below:

```
$myAssocArray = [
[ 'Name' => 'AWS_Bucket-Name1',  'Value' => 'Bucket data',...],
[ 'Name' => 'AWS_Bucket-Name2',  'Value' => 'Bucket data',...],
[ 'Name' => 'AWS_Bucket-Name3',  'Value' => 'Bucket data',...],
[ 'Name' => 'AWS_Bucket-Name4',  'Value' => 'Bucket data',...],
];
```

From this I want to create a simple associative array like below:

```
[ ['AWS_Bucket-Name1' => 'Bucket data'], ['AWS_Bucket-Name2' => 'Bucket data'], ...]
```

So I can take two approaches to resolve this:

(1) Use `array_map` function in php:

```
$destinationArray = array_map('myMapFunction', $myAssocArray);

function myMapFunction($entity): array {
   if (is_array($entity) && isset($entity['Name'], $entity['Value'])) {
      return [$entity['Name'] => $entity['Value']];
    }
}
```

OR

(2) Using `array_column` and `array_combine` functions:

```
$keys = array_column($myAssocArray, 'Name');
$values = array_column($myAssocArray, 'Value');
$destinationArray = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

**What will be more recommended approach and which will be more performant and efficient? OR is there even better solution available that does not need foreach loop?**

Comment: The array_map method gives you more of an opportunity to handle missing/unexpected/inconsistent values in your input data. array_column/combine is simpler to write, but you lose that level of control. Performance/efficiency will be fairly similar. I don't think this is an area where you can expect optimization to get you big performance gains.

Comment: Instead of array_column and array_combine, I would suggest convert your array into collection and then apply pluck method. like this. `collect($myAssocArray)->pluck('Value', 'Name')->toArray();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't look at the performance here because these operations are very small. I would focus more on the clean code side.

`array_map()` solution is harder to understand at the first look.

You don't need to use `array_combine()` and double invocation of `array_column()`. Instead you can pass third argument to `array_column()` which is

> "index key"
>   The column to use as the index/keys for the returned array. This value may be the integer key of the column, or it may be the string key name.

The following code

```
array_column($myAssocArray, 'Value', 'Name')
```

prints the same output as desired.

Have in mind that PHP internally can notice and optimize a lot of things to improve performance. Obviously, it's better when developer does so, but sometimes you gain 1 μs of performance with the cost of clean code and headache of a developer maintaining that code.

- [Working fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6479a589213f660a3ddabd2e8ff0c5e1dcb74395)
- More info on [php.net/array_column](http://php.net/array_column)